# How do I connect to Postgresql using SSL from SqlAchemy+pg8000?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pg8000

Connecting to postgres via pg8000 from SqlAlchemy worked fine until I enabled SSL on postgres.

```
db = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@hostname/dbname', echo=True).connect()
```

Now it seems to fail with:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 872, in __init__
raise InterfaceError("communication error", exc_info()[1])
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) ('communication error', error(61, 'Connection refused')) None None
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add a `connect_args` dict:

```py
db = create_engine(
    'postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@hostname/dbname',
    connect_args={'sslmode':'require'},
    echo=True,
).connect()
```

Comment: In fact it seems that it is able to defect sslmode by itself, as I was connecting to the wrong host. Still, is very good to know how to enforce-ssl mode. Thanks.

Comment: note this can be stated inline more easily:  `create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://user:pass@hostname/dbname?sslmode=require')`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer no longer works, at least with these versions:

```
Python                   3.9
pg8000                   1.19.5
SQLAlchemy               1.4.12
```

The [pg8000 docs](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#connect-to-postgresql-over-ssl) describe what you have to do. Use

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://user:password@host/db', 
                       connect_args={'ssl_context': True})
```

which passes the result of [ssl.create_default_context()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context) to the connection creator.  If a custom SSL context is required, pass it as the value instead of `True`:

```
import ssl

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
# Set attributes as required  ...

engine = create_engine('postgresql+pg8000://user:password@host/db', 
                       connect_args={'ssl_context': ssl_context})
```