# Connecting Python/pandas to Redshift when SSL is required

Tags: python, ssl, pandas, psycopg2, amazon-redshift

My company recently changed our Redshift cluster and now they require an SSL connection. In the past I've connected Python/pandas to Redshift via the method I've detailed here: http://measureallthethin.gs/blog/connect-python-and-pandas-to-redshift/

From the SQLAlchemy documentation, looks like all I need to do is add `connect_args={'sslmode':'require'}` to the `create_engine()` call, as this thread pointed out: [How do I connect to Postgresql using SSL from SqlAchemy+pg8000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095591/how-do-i-connect-to-postgresql-using-ssl-from-sqlachemypg8000)

However, I now get this error:

> OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in

I use the Anaconda distribution for a number of packages, and found I needed to update my psycopg2 package per these instructions: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/conda/Fqv93VKQXAc/mHqfNK8xZWsJ

However, even after updating psycopg2 I'm still getting the same error and am at a loss at this point on how to further debug. I'd like to figure this out so I can get our Redshift data directly into pandas.

Comment: Try using either "verify-full" or "verify-ca".  When I had previously tried connecting using any other sslmode, I received the message:"[Amazon](500155) The value for property sslmode is invalid. Valid values are: verify-full, verify-ca."

Answer (score 1):

AWS has developed an Amazon Redshift connector for Python ([here is the GitHub repo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver)) that helps in the process.

In order to install it on may install from the source

```
git clone https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver.git
cd redshift_connector
pip install .
```

Or from the binary using [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/)

```
pip install redshift_connector
```

Or [Conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/redshift_connector)

```
conda install -c conda-forge redshift_connector
```

Here is an example

```
import redshift_connector

# Connects to Redshift cluster using AWS credentials
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host='examplecluster.abc123xyz789.us-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
    database='dev',
    user='awsuser',
    password='my_password'
 )

cursor: redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create Temp table book(bookname varchar,author varchar)")
cursor.executemany("insert into book (bookname, author) values (%s, %s)",
                    [
                        ('One Hundred Years of Solitude', 'Gabriel García Márquez'),
                        ('A Brief History of Time', 'Stephen Hawking')
                    ]
                  )
cursor.execute("select * from book")

result: tuple = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
>> (['One Hundred Years of Solitude', 'Gabriel García Márquez'], ['A Brief History of Time', 'Stephen Hawking'])
```

Note that one of the [Connection Parameters](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver#connection-parameters) one can pass is SSL (If SSL is enabled). The default value is `TRUE`.

Comment: for anyone considering this for *aws lambda*... :thumbs-down: `redshift_connector` didn't work for my lambda use.  i bundled it but lambda wanted `scramp` and then `asn1crypto` and then i stopped.  know how to do this for _aws lambda?_

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver/issues/15) of help to you? Is the scrap issue similar to [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver/issues/34)?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this ?

```
pip3 install pg8000


import pg8000
host =  "***.amazonaws.com"
port = 5439

db_name = "dev"
master_username = "dev"
master_user_password = 'TestPassword1'


connection = pg8000.connect(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    database=db_name,
    user=master_username,
    password=master_user_password,
)
connection.autocommit = True
import uuid
prefix = 'table_'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  table_name = f"{prefix}{str(uuid.uuid4())[:4]}"
  tbl_create_sql = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (a int, b int);"
  cursor.execute(tbl_create_sql)
  # Step 2: insert a number of rows
  ROWS_TO_INSERT = 5
```